# Is it ok to use latest mongo driver with spring mongodb

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

Spring MongoDb is still stuck with v 2.10 of the mongo client.
is it ok to use a more recent version of the mongo driver with spring mongodb or will that break things?

Comment: Can you try? Surely you just add the dependency to your POM (assuming Maven) and do a local build and test.

Comment: because that would be stupid. my code doesnt cover all the cases and i dont want it to silently break in the future.

Comment: I didn't say "deploy it to production", I said **try it**. If It **breaks** then you have something to report. Notice the sound of tumbleweeds here? Please don't expect people to do your work for you. So I suggested **you** try something yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use Spring Data MongoDB with newer versions of the Java driver than the one declared in the POM. Spring Data MongoDB is not *stuck* with 2.10. We generally handle the versions and version upgrades for Spring Data modules as follows:

A root GA release (x.x.0) ships declared with the latest version of a dependency at the time of the release. For the current Spring Data MongoDB version 1.3.4.RELEASE this was version 1.3.0.RELEASE (September, 2013. It refers to the Mongo Driver in version 2.10.1 which was the latest at that point in time.

The version declaration means: we built against this dependency, and have run integration tests. This of course does *not* mean that you have to use this particular dependency version with the library. You can effectively use any more recent version of it as long as it stays compatible with the version we compiled against. **So version declarations for *all* transitive dependencies are lower boundaries up to versions of the dependencies that break APIs or semantics**.

We generally do *not* raise dependency versions within bug fix releases to not force users in having to upgrade transitive dependencies just to be able to benefit from a bug fix on our side. However - as explained above - nobody prevents you from using a newer version of the dependency in general.

For the upcoming 1.4 release of Spring Data MongoDB we're on driver version 2.11.4 already and just have added some [compatibility tweaks](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-848?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-bitbucket-connector-plugin%3advcs-commits-tabpanel) to make sure the release will be compatible with the upcoming 2.12 release of the driver.